# Memory tracking in a go program

Tags: memory-leaks, go

The memory consumption in my go program is steadily growing over time.
Is there a way I can find out which code lines are allocating the memory?My go binary is running in an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: I beg you pardon, but why do you need some way when you just can read your code.

Basically all var, new, {}, &{} and const allocate memory this way or another. The compiler decides which case should be heap allocated and which is stack one.

Comment: @Denis, the codebase is very large. Not sure its practical to read all the code to find out the leaks.

Comment: Yeah, @alokaggarwal, sorry you've got the point.

And GoMetaLinter much helps by the way =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you'll find some help here: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/